# I want to reverse the key and value of Map

Tags: flutter

How can I reverse the key and value of the map?

for example, `{1:a , 2:b , 3:c} => {a:1 ,b:2 ,c:3}`

Comment: What effort have you made? What if there’s multiple keys that have the same value?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```dart
const items = {1:'a' , 2:'b' , 3:'c'};

void main() {
  final inverted = items.map((key, value) => MapEntry(value, key));
  print(inverted);
}
```

It logs

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code:

```
Map<int, String> map = {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c"};

  Iterable<String> values = map.values;
  Iterable<int> keys = map.keys;
  Map<String, int> reversedMap = Map.fromIterables(values, keys);

  print(reversedMap); // {a:1 ,b:2 ,c:3}
```